# when I am using ":" in typescript that time, compilation happening correctly but during run time it is getting failed

Tags: typescript

I was trying to run one of the .ts file from visual studio code and sublime text. Compilation is happening properly. But I am getting error during run time.

I have installed typescript globally in my system through node. I have installed typescript compiler in sublime. Tried same code online editor it is working fine. 
My type script version is 3.6.3

I have written below code

```
let a: number=2;
let b: string="hi";
let c: boolean= true;

console.log(a+" "+b+" "+c);

C:\Users\pbhadury>tsc prasanta.ts

C:\Users\pbhadury>node prasanta.ts
C:\Users\pbhadury\prasanta.ts:1
let a:string="Hi"
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: You are running the ts file directly, you need to build it and run the resulting js file. Or use `ts-node` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)